# How can I prove this? $(a^2+b^2)\cdot(c^2+d^2) = A^2+B^2$, and $a,b,c,d,A,B \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus

Prove that the product of two sums of squares is a sum of squares, that is, if $a, b, c, d$ are integers, then it is possible to find integers $A, B$ such that $$(a^2+b^2) (c^2+d^2) = A^2+B^2.$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity

Comment: Writing $(a^2+b^2)=(a+ib)(a-bi)=\alpha\bar{\alpha}$ and $(c^2+d^2)=(c+id)(c-di)=\beta\bar{\beta}$ you get that $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(\alpha\beta)(\overline{\alpha\beta})$ and the righthandside gives you again the sum of two squares.

Comment: ¡Thanks for the help!